# How can a disk without a partition be "partitioned" on Windows without losing data?

Tags: partition, windows, ext4, vmware, ntfs

I have a 1TB portable hard drive that I use for backups.

The entire drive (`/dev/sdb`) has been formatted as an `ext4` filesystem.
But I am now on Windows and I need to get back those files...

I tried using Ubuntu virtual machines with VMware and a shared folder to convert the data into `ntfs` but the disk won't show up!

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to transfer the data from the Linux file system `ext4` to a Microsoft file system (NTFS, FAT32 or exFAT).

0. It is a good idea to avoid writing into the Windows partition (C:). It is better to write into some other partition with the NTFS (or exFAT) file system, because it decreases the risk to damage the Windows operating system. At least backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (personal files in Windows) before copying from Linux to the Windows partition (C:).
1. I suggest **a straight-forward way using Linux** booted on bare metal of your computer (not in a virtual machine). You need not have it installed, but can run Linux live or persistent live booted from a USB pendrive.
2. When running Linux, you can read and write Microsoft file systems. If there are problems to mount read-write (to get write permissions), please **reboot** Windows (instead of shutdown) and from there boot directly into Linux. Otherwise the Microsoft file systems might be 'dirty' because of hibernation or Fast Startup (semi-hibernation). If still problems, see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).
3. Now you should be able to copy files from Linux to the Microsoft file system.